# Не получается сделать git push по ssh

Tags: ubuntu, git, github, ssh

У меня `Ubuntu 20.04`. Пытаюсь сделать `git push` по ssh:

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.

Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа
и репозиторий существует.
```

Ключи я создал, публичный ключ залил на github. Причем я заметил, что под ключем написано: "ни разу не использован". По https пушит нормально, но во-первых, приходится вводить пароль, а во-вторых, каждый раз приходит письмо "Deprecation notice", в котором написано, что http-push будет удален в следующих версиях. В чем может быть проблема?

Вот список того, что я уже пробовал:

1. Пересоздать ключи
2. Перезагрузить службу ssh
3. Переустановить ssh-client и ssh-server

**P.P.S.** Не знаю, возможно это важно: недавно возникли проблемы с подключением по ssh к серверу. При попытке подключения через терминал выводилась ошибка: `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`. Стандартные методы, вроде `ServerAliveInterval 120` не помогли. Решилось все установкой вот такой галочки в настройках роутера (если честно, без понятия, что это значит, но помогло)

[image: Скрин настроек роутера]

Видимо какая-то проблема с ключами, но я делал все в точности по этой [инструкции](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) от GitHub

**UPD:**
выполнил тестовое подключение, похоже дело все-таки не в ключах:

```
$ ssh -Tvvv  git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/danny/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-517b8896
debug1: no match: babeld-517b8896
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/danny/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/danny/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/danny/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/danny/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/danny/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/danny/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 140.82.121.4
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/danny/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/danny/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Oq185RPr6ezhG8qQfCv5ZmY9jcLDNSF4zyFO6KKP2RM agent
debug1: Will attempt key: example@yandex.ru RSA SHA256:j6ZYhL5mWQrkVEEK/JYMKQB/ZiHZKN16z098To0PtqM agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/danny/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/danny/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/danny/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/danny/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/danny/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/danny/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/danny/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Oq185RPr6ezhG8qQfCv5ZmY9jcLDNSF4zyFO6KKP2RM agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: example@yandex.ru RSA SHA256:j6ZYhL5mWQrkVEEK/JYMKQB/ZiHZKN16z098To0PtqM agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: example@yandex.ru RSA SHA256:j6ZYhL5mWQrkVEEK/JYMKQB/ZiHZKN16z098To0PtqM agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:j6ZYhL5mWQrkVEEK/JYMKQB/ZiHZKN16z098To0PtqM
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:j6ZYhL5mWQrkVEEK/JYMKQB/ZiHZKN16z098To0PtqM
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.121.4]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug3: send packet: type 1
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

При этом подключиться к другой сети тоже не помогло (попробовал раздать интернет с телефона) -- та же ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После 5 часов в интернете, я нашел нечто, что помогло мне. Если вы столкнетесь с такой же проблемой, то нужно:

### Вариант 1

1. Если у вас нет файла конфигурации ssh, создайте его: `touch ~/.ssh/config`, и добавьте необходимые разрешения: `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`
2. Добавьте в этот файл следующее содержимое:

   ```
   Host *
      IPQoS 0x00
   ```
3. Перезапустите ssh: `sudo systemctl restart ssh`

После этого должно заработать.

Этот ответ нашел вот [здесь](https://wiki.debian.org/SSH#Resolution_with_IPQoS_0x00)

---

### Вариант 2

На [аглоязычном стаке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415943/trying-to-git-clone-via-ssh-but-getting-broken-pipe-error) нашел вот такое решение проблемы:

1. Первый шаг как и в пункте выше
2. В файл конфигурации нужно записать:

   ```
   Host *
       ServerAliveInterval 600
       TCPKeepAlive yes
       IPQoS=throughput
   ```
3. Третий шаг такой же.

Но конкретно в моем случае это не сработало, не знаю, почему.

---

Надеюсь, что помогу кому-то.